# Shift div upward to fill empty space in Bootstrap 3 layout

Tags: css, layout, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

I have a [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) layout that reorders itself the way I want it to when it goes to 1-column at the smallest media query size of `xs`:

```
[A]
[B]
[IMG]
[C]
[D]
[E]
```

At higher screen sizes, I want it to look like this:

```
[A][IMG]
[B][E]
[C]
[D]
```

Instead, it currently looks like this:

```
[A]
[B][IMG]
[C]
[D][E]
```

Here's a [demo](http://codepen.io/thompcha/pen/VLQpPm?editors=100).

How can I make the image and the div on the right "float" upward to fill the empty space?

Comment: I'm open to solutions that aren't purely CSS and HTML

Answer (score 0):

Then you should put you columns in that order.

Like this:

`[A], [IMG], [B], [E], [C], [D]`

Your current order is:

`[A], [B], [IMG], [C], [D], [E]`

See the updated [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BNYWmx).

I am aware that the mobile layout will then be in a different order, but you cannot rearrange DOM elements with just CSS

Comment: That gives me the wrong order when it snaps to one column.

Comment: You are trying to rearrange your `col-` divs in a different order depending on screen size. This is not possible with just CSS. You may want to refine your layout

Answer (score 0):

You need a little js to move columns up and down within the order...

```
if ($(window).width() > 767) {
       $("#img").insertBefore("#b");
       $("#e").insertBefore("#c");
    }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/w46wbf9y/1/

Note: You'll have to reload the fiddle after each window resize, which is fine if you're targeting devices, but if you want it to react on browser resizing too, you'll need slightly more complex js.

And like @zgood says, you need to start with the mobile div order as base.